# Terraform AWS SES credential resource

Tags: terraform, amazon-ses

I've searched but no information found.
Can we create AWS SES credential by using terraform?

Answer (score 53):

Use the following terraform code to get SES credentials -

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "smtp_user" {
  name = "smtp_user"
}

resource "aws_iam_access_key" "smtp_user" {
  user = aws_iam_user.smtp_user.name
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "ses_sender" {
  statement {
    actions   = ["ses:SendRawEmail"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ses_sender" {
  name        = "ses_sender"
  description = "Allows sending of e-mails via Simple Email Service"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.ses_sender.json
}

resource "aws_iam_user_policy_attachment" "test-attach" {
  user       = aws_iam_user.smtp_user.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ses_sender.arn
}

output "smtp_username" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.smtp_user.id
}

output "smtp_password" {
  value = aws_iam_access_key.smtp_user.ses_smtp_password_v4
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Couldn't find an official documentation with an example. If you could find any, you can share the link here. Upvoted!

Comment: Awesome. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Newer versions of Terraofrm might require to set `sensitive = true` to the output of the SMTP password.

Answer (score 1):

aws ses smtp credentials are iam credentials converted to smtp credentials. You should create a iam user and output them as smtp credentials like with the module below 
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-iam/tree/master/examples/iam-user

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.